# Node.js gives error "Can't find variable require"

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm trying to connect to my local mysql database by using node.js on my website. I have installed node.js on my laptop. This is my code that is executed:

```
function registerUser()
{
    var mysql = require("mysql");

    var connection = mysql.createConnection( {
                                            host: 'localhost',
                                            user: 'root',
                                            password: '',
                                            database: 'Fountaint_News_Database',
                                            port: 3306
                                            });

    connection.connect();

    var query = connection.query('INSERT INTO registered_users VALUES ("test", 22)',
                                 function(err, result, fields) {
                                 if (err) throw err;
                                 console.log('result: ', result);
                                 });

    connection.end();

    console.log('Connection closed');
}
```

I haven't done anything else, I'm not sure if there is anything else to setup, but when I runt I just get this error "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require".

I hope that someone can help me.

Comment: where exactly are you trying to execute this piece of code? on browser or by `node <yourfile>.js`?

Comment: in a browser... I have a form with a register button and when clicked, this function is called

Comment: you might want to check this http://stackoverflow.com/tags/node.js/info

Answer (score 1):

Are you running this code on the server side, not on the client don't you? I mean saving this file on a .js file, running via console via

```
node yourfile.js
```

after obviously a

```
npm install mysql
```

in the same directory?

Obviously you need to bind the registerUser() function to some event :)